# JavaMail - Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Tags: java, smtp, office365, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to use JavaMail to send emails through office365 valid account. However, I am receiving the same exception '530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM'. Following the simple code I am using for testing:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.debug", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(USER_NAME, USER_PASS);
    }
});

try {
    final Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(USER_NAME));
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(USER_NAME));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(messageContent);
    message.setSentDate(new Date());
    Transport.send(message);
    System.out.println("Send OK");
} catch (final MessagingException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Following the debug output:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.3
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\lib\javamail.providers (The system cannot find the file specified)
DEBUG: !anyLoaded
DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: !anyLoaded
DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\lib\javamail.address.map (The system cannot find the file specified)
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true

DEBUG: SMTPTransport trying to connect to host "smtp.office365.com", port 587

DEBUG SMTP RCVD: 220 xxxxx.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 6 Jun 2019 07:53:32 +0000

DEBUG: SMTPTransport connected to host "smtp.office365.com", port: 587

DEBUG SMTP SENT: EHLO L3343005201
DEBUG SMTP RCVD: 250-xxxxx.outlook.office365.com Hello [92.242.173.14]
250-SIZE 157286400
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

DEBUG SMTP Found extension "SIZE", arg "157286400"
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
DEBUG SMTP SENT: MAIL FROM:<sender@domain>
DEBUG SMTP RCVD: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [xxxxx.yyyyy.outlook.com]

DEBUG SMTP SENT: QUIT
Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [xxxxx.yyyyy]
```

From logs it seems the authentication is not working, and the connection port goes to 25 rather than the 587 as specified in the properties.

I tried adding other properties as well, like

```
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.user", USER_NAME);
props.put("mail.smtp.password", USER_PASS);
props.put("mail.smtp.from", USER_NAME);
```

in any combination, but no results.
I've also tried to use the updated version of the JavaMail library, but the exception is the same. Am I missing any configuration on the mail account? Or from code?

Thanks in advance

Edited: changing the port from 587 (int) to "587" (string) solved the port issue in the debug port, but the same Client authentication error occurs

Comment: Office365 doesn't allow authentication on a non-TLS-secured connection. You have to switch to TLS when using a plain connection. You can do that by setting the session property `mail.smtp.starttls.enable`to `true`

Comment: Hi @Lothar The property is already set, among with "mail.smtp.auth" as "true"

Comment: You've also set `mail.smtp.port` to `587` while the debug log shows the connection to happen to port `25`.

Comment: @Lothar that's also another strange thing, as mentioned in my post. It seems it's trying to use a default instance instead of a new instance as specified by the Session.getInstance method

Comment: @Lothar the port issue was because the port should be a string. however, even with the port 587, the same error occurs

Comment: Just to be on the "complete" side, set the properties `mail.transport.protocol` to `smtp` and the property `mail.smtp.socketFactory.class` to `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`. Oh, and for the future ;-) use `setProperty` instead of `put`.

Comment: @Lothar I've switched to setProperty :) the addition of the socketFactory property causes the following exception:

Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
 class javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 587

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaMail 1.3 is 17 years old!  Where did you find it?  Switch to the [current release](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release) and then fix all these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).

Comment: I've updated all the project libs to the latest version, including JavaMail, and now it works like a charm. Thanks!